# Calling an alert box from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I want to do is call an alert dialog box from within the controller.
The reasoning is because the controller is called by the view via an ajax call and does not reload the page thus would not be able to compare any new data in a tempdata or otherwise.

The purpose of the action is to check if the student checking into the class is supposed to be there or not. If the class is not in their schedule then the permission bool remains false and an alert should pop up stating that the student is not in the class.

```
public ActionResult Action(string ccod, int sid)
    {
        IEnumerable<MvcStudentTracker.Databases.Course> result = from course in db.Courses
                    join sched in db.Schedules on course.CourseCode equals sched.ClassCode
                    where sched.StuID == sid
                    select course;
        bool permission = false;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            if (item.CourseCode == ccod)
                permission = true;
        }

        if (permission == false)
        {
            //call alert dialog box "This student is not signed up for this class"
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Why not return a `JsonResult` with the `permission` state and then in the success of your Ajax call use that value to display the alert?

Comment: Or, if you really wanted to, just set a ViewBag variable and use it when declaring your JS function to show the dialog box.

Comment: Because I'm new to mvc and didn't know that was an option. I'll give those a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change your action so it returns a `JsonResult` object. This way we can easily manipulate its results on the client side. As you are already calling it using javascript, that's the best solution.

So, your **action**:

```
public JsonResult Action(string ccod, int sid)
{
    IEnumerable<MvcStudentTracker.Databases.Course> result = from course in db.Courses
                join sched in db.Schedules on course.CourseCode equals sched.ClassCode
                where sched.StuID == sid
                select course;

    return Json(result.Any(x => x.CourseCode == ccod), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And your **view**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'root/Action',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        ccod: $('...').val()
        , sid: $('...').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data) {
        //ok!
    }
    else {
        //permission denied
    }
});
```

Note that I've changed your action code. You may want to review it and change it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alrt", "alert('Anything');", true);
```

like htis

```
 public ActionResult Action(string ccod, int sid)
        {
            IEnumerable<MvcStudentTracker.Databases.Course> result = from course in db.Courses
                        join sched in db.Schedules on course.CourseCode equals sched.ClassCode
                        where sched.StuID == sid
                        select course;
            bool permission = false;
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                if (item.CourseCode == ccod)
                    permission = true;
            }

            if (permission == false)
            {
                //call alert dialog box "This student is not signed up for this class"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alrt", "alert('This student is not signed up for this class');", true);
            }
            return null;

        }
```